# How to initiate DragDrop in Windows Universal Apps and XAML?

Tags: wpf, windows, universal

I am developing a windows universal app with XAML / C# and i want to drag an rectangle in order to dop it anywhere else.
In former projects (e.g. for Windows 7 applications) i have been able to initiate drag n drop by using the `DragDrop` Class and `doDragDrop`. This class is not available in my universal app.
How can i dragdrop in universal apps? How can i reference the DragDrop class?

Comment: Is the rectangle you want to drag inside of GridView or ListView, or it is standalone?

Comment: No, it is a rect e. g. in a stackpanel or grid.

Answer (score 1):

Finaly i found help at this site: [link](https://dotnetexpertise.wordpress.com/category/windows-store-apps/)